# How to chage array key value without change array formate in php

Tags: php

Can you please explain how to change one array value to second value.

Please find below example.

*First array*

```
Array
(
    [20239802] => one test
    [20239801] => two testttttt
)
```

*Second array*

```
Array (
    [content] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [content_pack_id] => 10002
            [content_pack_name] => 100 Days Of Love-FLA
            [image_path] => Array ( [0] => pack_image_10002_width. )
            [content_image_path] => Array ( [imgjpeg80] => http://content.jpg )
            [content_id] => 20239802
            [track] => Lede Inthati Santhosham
            [duration] => 0
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [content_pack_id] => 10003
            [content_pack_name] => 1001 fdfdf 
            [image_path] => Array ( [0] => pack_image_10002_width. )    
            [content_image_path] => Array ( [imgjpeg80] => http://content.jpg )    
            [content_id] => 20239801
            [track] => Lede Inthati Santhosham
            [duration] => 0
        )
    )
    [autoshuffle_pack] => no
)
```

We need to replace `[track]` value in second array if match first array `[20239802]` with  second array `[content_id]`

Need out put:-

```
Array
(
    [content] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [content_pack_id] => 10002
                    [content_pack_name] => 100 Days Of Love-FLA
                    [image_path] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => pack_image_10002_width.
                        )

                    [content_image_path] => Array
                        (

                            [imgjpeg80] => http://content.jpg
                        )

                    [content_id] => 20239802
                    [track] => one test
                    [duration] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [content_pack_id] => 10003
                    [content_pack_name] => 1001 fdfdf 
                    [image_path] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => pack_image_10002_width.
                        )

                    [content_image_path] => Array
                        (

                            [imgjpeg80] => http://content.jpg
                        )

                    [content_id] => 20239801
                    [track] => two testttttt
                    [duration] => 0
                )   
        )

    [autoshuffle_pack] => no
)
```

Check [track] value change in my need out put

as per depend first array.

```
Array
(
    [20239802] => one test
    [20239801] => two testttttt
)
```

with second array

```
[content_id] => 20239801
[track] => two testttttt
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want to replace. Can you provide in your question the expected output?

Comment: I this this link will help you a bit. It will explain two methods with code example. Check http://blog.vijayrana.com.np/blog/2016/03/14/how-to-change-the-key-of-an-array-element/

Answer (score 2):

Is this you want to do :

```
foreach($second_array as $key => $second_row) {
    $content_id = $second_row['content_id'];
    if(isset($first_array[$content_id]) && $first_array[$content_id] != '') {
        $second_array['track'] = $first_array[$content_id];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do you own function.

Foreach records in your first array:

- Loop though the second and search for `key == content_id`
- If it matched, set the value of `array2[$index][track]` to `array1[key]`
- If not just continue

You can also use `array_search()` function to find the match faster, for I'll let you take a look at the `PHP` documentation